# Preserve line breaks and carriage return characters when using .val() in textarea - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html -:

```
<div id="myEditor" contenteditable="true"></div>
<textarea id="myArea"></textarea>
```

I have this jquery code -:

```
$("#myEditor").live("paste",function(){ 
var $this = $(this); 

setTimeout(function(){ $("#myArea").val($this.text()); },2);
                                     });
```

But when i use the above jquery code, all the line breaks and carriage returns are stripped off.

From Jquery documentation, I even tried using this , but in vain -:

```
$.valHooks.textarea = {
get: function( elem ) {
return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" );
}                     };
```

But when I manually copy everything from div and paste it into textarea, line breaks are well preserved..
 How do go about this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$.valHooks.textarea = {
get: function( elem ) {
return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "<br />" );
}                     };
```